# Java common Try/Finally block around different code blocks - code style

Tags: java, code-standards

I have the *same* `if() { try { < SOME CODE > } finally { } } else {}` block that I use in 3 methods.

The only thing that's different in each method is < SOME CODE >.

Are there any coding patterns that I can use to "DRY" my code? Ideally would like to extract the `if() { try { } finally { } } else {}` to some common structure and pass the < SOME CODE > to it. Is that possible in Java?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is possible. I don't think it is worth the effort. You will need to change the code in the `finally` block based on the resources used in the `try` block. What if various `try` blocks throw different exceptions? How are you going to catch them?

Comment: not planning to handle any exceptions in that block of the code. Instead I would expect exceptions to be thrown up. Finally {} block is important as that's where I am doing some cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a common method to factor out the common part.

Then according to your requirements you could do :

1) if the 3 methods are in the same  class : extracting each set of statements of the `try` bodies in 3 specific methods and pass this method as a `Runnable` parameter in the common method.
For example :

```
public void commonMethod(Runnable methodToInvoke){

     if() {
            try { methodToInvoke.run() } finally { } 
     } 
     else {}
}
```

And call it by passing the 3 extracted methods :

```
commonMethod(this::methodFoo);
commonMethod(this::methodBar);
commonMethod(this::methodFooBar);
```

2) if the 3 methods are in distinct classes : introducing an interface that the 3 classes will implement and make the common method accept a parameter of this interface.

For example with a `Processing` interface introduced :

```
public void commonMethod(Processing processing){

     if() {
            try { processing.doThat() } finally { } 
     } 
     else {}
}
```

And call it by passing the 3 implementations of the `Processing` interface :

```
commonMethod(foo);
commonMethod(bar);
commonMethod(fooBar);
```

Comment: The 3 methods are indeed in the same class. In fact this is a Spring Controller class that has the 3 methods that handle UI actions. With introduction of `Runnable` I will be effectively kicking off separate thread for each call to the method, which could lead to undesirable results.

Comment: @JohnFitch the fact that you call `Runnable.run` somewhere in your code doesn't mean that you start a new thread. To spawn new thread you either need to create `Thread` object explicitly or submit `Runnable` to thread pool.

Comment: Ivan is right. I used the `Runnable` interface as its functional descriptor matches perfectly to invoke a method : the `run()` method takes no arg and is `void`.  So yes you don't need and don't have to introduce threads if your actual code didn't need them.